# Обновление содержимого Listbox Tkinter

Tags: python, tkinter, pyttsx3

Проблема заключается в том что Listbox обновляется после окончания работы функции turn, как сделать так что бы в Listbox добавлялись фразы сразу после того как эту фразу произнесли

```
import pyttsx3
from tkinter import *

engine = pyttsx3.init('sapi5')
voices = engine.getProperty('voices')
engine.setProperty('voice', voices[1].id)

def speak(msg):
    engine.say(msg)
    engine.runAndWait()
    msg_list.insert(END, msg)

def turn():
    speak("Hello")
    speak("How are you")
    speak("Some text")

root = Tk()
root.title("Voice")
root.minsize(500, 500)

button_speak = Button(text='test', command=turn).pack()
messages_frame = Frame()
scrollbar = Scrollbar(messages_frame)
msg_list = Listbox(messages_frame, height=15, width=100, yscrollcommand=scrollbar.set)
scrollbar.pack(side=RIGHT, fill=Y)
msg_list.pack(side=LEFT, fill=BOTH)
messages_frame.pack()

root.mainloop()
```

Comment: Спасибо большое, все работает

Comment: В общем да, как костыльное решение можно добавить `root.update()` в конец метода `speak`, но более правильно будет убрать `engine.runAndWait()` и добавление строки в список делать через подписку на событие `'finished-utterance'` (событие завершения произнесения фразы, см. [`Engine.connect`](https://pyttsx3.readthedocs.io/en/latest/engine.html#pyttsx3.engine.Engine.connect)). Протестировать этот вариант и написать ответ пока не могу, потому что они похоже сломали поддержку linux.